# Trying to have an image fade in on load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have an image fade in on load, but its not working.

HTML

```
<div class="carl-dair">
        <a href="pages/about.html"><img src="images/carl-dair.png"></a>
</div>
```

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#carl-dair').load fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated since I'm a complete beginner at JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I said in comment you used `class="carl-dair"` and used it as an Id in js `$('#carl-dair')` so change it to `$('.carl-dair')`

wrong way to use it like that

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#carl-dair').load fadeIn("slow");
});
```

try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.carl-dair img').on('load',function(){
     $(this).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

be sure in css  display it to none

```
.carl-dair img{
   display : none;
}
```

if in css you use

```
.carl-dair{
   display : none;
}
```

and want to show the #carl-dair div after image load  you can use

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.carl-dair img').on('load',function(){
         $(this).closest('.carl-dair').fadeIn("slow");
      });
    });
```

and no need to display image to none

something you should know

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser It doesn't
>   fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
>   before It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree Can cease to fire
>   for images that already live in the browser's cache

source https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

so instead of `.load()` .. use `.on('load',function(){})`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/99cpmryh/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still does not fad in for some reason.

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, i was using a wrong jquery file. thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure yet, still trying to figure things out. but i know for sure that i was using different jquery file haha

Comment: @ahtodesign but check that you use class="carl-dair"  and use it as a ID in jquery $('#carl-dair') .. change to $('.carl-dair')

Comment: The page that's linked to at the bottom also shows it's been deprecated like this...

Comment: @Shikkediel that is why I mention that to him in my answer ... and update my answer now :)